# How to find a greedy solution in a list with duplicates

Tags: python, duplicates, scheduling, greedy

I am trying to solve a sequencing/scheduling problem. In this work I have encountered a problem regarding finding a greedy solution for a sequence with duplicates.
My initial sequence looks like this: [2, 9, 4, 11, 11] (or can be similar, containing duplicates).
My algorithm will select an arbitrary/random number of the sequence as its first element and then further pick the elements of lowest value as the following elements.
The code I have proposed is as follows:

```
l = [2, 9, 4, 11, 11]
t=l.copy()
seq = [random.randint(0,N-1)]
i = 0
while i < N:
 a = min(t)
 if seq[0] == i:
   i +=1
 else:
    seq.append(l.index(a))
    t.remove(t[t.index(a)])
    i+=1
print(seq)
```

One example of a solution from this code is: [3, 0, 2, 1, 3], which is not desired as I want it to be [1, 0, 2, 1, 4].
Thanks for the help!

Comment: do not understand your requirement, can you give a example which describe input list, picked number, then expected output list,

Comment: Yes, i understand now that i might have been unclear.
My input is a random list of integers. I want to return a list of the indices to the integers in its sorted rising order. This must also handle duplicates.
Input: [2, 1, 3, 1]
Output: [1, 3, 0, 2]

Comment: can you edit your question with the clarification

Answer (score 1):

Now the problem is clear: you're trying to return a list of the indices to the integers in its sorted rising order. I have a solution for that.

```
def sort(lst):
    # Make 2d array containing elements and their index
    pairs = [[num,ind] for ind, num in enumerate(lst)]
    
    sorted_indices = []
    
    # Go through sorted pairs and collect indices into sorted_indices
    for pair in sorted(pairs):
        sorted_indices.append(pair[1])
        
    return sorted_indices
```

Test:

```
sort([2, 1, 3, 1])
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 0, 2]
```